# Why I cannot access the svn server from remote?

Tags: iptables, firewall, subversion

I used svnserve on my centOS server. And I have open port number 3690 on my server. As you can see, the result of command *iptables -L* is shown as following

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:mysql 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:5901 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ddi-tcp-1 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:svn 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:search-agent 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:svn
```

And I have started svnserve on my server, as I can check out successfully on my server with command *svn co svn://ip address/name*.
Nevertheless, when I try to check out from my laptop. It is said that connection is refused. And also, I have tested the connection by *telnet ip port* , it is said telnet: Unable to connect to remote host. It is quite confused since I have open port 3690 and my svn service is definitely listening to port 3690. What could be the reason for that? And what should I do to access the svn server from remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPtables process the rules from top to the bottom.
Here is the issue:

Take look on the following rules:

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:svn
```

After `Reject all` rule all packets are discarded, including your `svn` rule. So that is why you're unable to connect.

**Solution:**

Place the following rule as the latest one on your INPUT chain, if you really want to discard all other packets:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```